# Call to a member function publish() on null when trying to pubish to redis on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, azure, laravel-5, redis

I am trying to publish stuff to redis but I get this error:

```
Call to a member function publish() on null.
```

Not sure whats going on. This is my code. Works well on the local environment but on the server the above error message shows. I have the following code in a controller. The website is hosted on windows azure appservice. I have also installed the predis/predis dependency.

```
$redis = Redis::connection(6380)->publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
```

Am I not connecting to redis or something?

Comment: Is your Redis connection actually named `6380` in `config/database.php`, or is that just the port?

Comment: can you please share you key `.env` and `/config` settings?

Comment: Seems like forced SSL for redis was was enabled. Disabling it and connecting of port 6379 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I go it working. The redis server on azure by default enforces SSL connections on port 6380. I disabled this so it allows non-SSL connections on port 6379. Now the connection is:

```
$redis = Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the connection name to the **connection()** method

```
$redis = Redis::connection('my_connection')->publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
```

or just skip it, if you intend to use the default connection.

```
$redis = Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
```

Redis connections should be defined in your **config/database.php** file.